# Arrange drupal 7 people/users admin page

Tags: drupal, view

I want to arrange the people's section of my drupal 7 admin page. Right now, the People/users are arranged according to usernames, status, roles, member for, ....etc. I want to make it look like last name, first name, employee id, ....etc (these are custom profile fields.) Then finally I want to arrange it alphabetically according to their last name. I have tried using views but ended up with the following two issues: 1. I couldn't find the custom profile fields like the first name, last name, ...etc, and 2. I have to either create a page or block to access the results of the views page (I want to make everything in the people's page.) I would real appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to /admin/people, you can create a page and use that path in your view, and it'll override the default /admin/people page. This is an explicit feature of the views module.

Bear in mind you'll have to mimic all the existing functionality you want to keep from the admin/people page (eg exposed filters and sorting), and make sure you set the access permissions on the view to ensure only admin users have access.

As for not being able to see custom profile fields, do you mean they're not showing up in the list of fields to select? I don't know why that would be... if you've created a view based on Users, then the fields will show up under the "User" category (User: first name, User: last name &c). I've checked my own install and everything's showing up fine. Further info?

Comment: Thank you Heather. My custom profiles type fields are not showing up in the list of fields to select. I have created custom profile types like personal information, business information and ... but none of them are showing up. I still don't have any idea as to how to mimic and list those users alphabetically.

Comment: When you say "custom profile types"... do you mean these are node types separate to the user (rather than user fields)? If that's the case, you'll need to create a relationship to the node content in order to see the fields in the list.

Comment: I created relationships and now they are showing up in the list, Many Thanks Heather!!!!

Comment: @SharenAnderson @HeatherGaye, is there any step-by-step tutorial/guide availale for this? As i want to achieve exactly the same results in my `drupal/admin/people`. I am new in drupal. Any help? Thx